# How can I make a connection with a device, on which an API is running, through IP?

Tags: java, eclipse, api

I can connect to the device using Putty with a Telnet connection and the API automatically starts up, allowing me to write commands in the shell.

I want to include the same functionality in my application but I cannot find any related topics after googling about it. The closest thing I found is [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Frse%2Fsubsystems%2Fshells%2Ftelnet%2Fpackage-summary.html) but I want the functionality with a GUI. For example, on a button click a specific command is sent through the API. My guess is I need a library, with which a communication can be opened over specified IP and port.

Comment: Can you provide more specific details. The above is vague.

Comment: @BrettWalker What details do you want to know about?

Comment: What device? What API? What commands? More details about what you are doing? Are you getting a map? Are you getting a news feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://javatelnet.org/space/start) project? Also, if you decide to implement an TCP-client application to send commands over telnet, you can put a [Netty](http://netty.io/) framework to good use.

Comment: No, I haven't. Thank you, I will certainly look into both links.